# Bootstrap nav blocks links in header above it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

this isn't a "**sticky menu**" problem.  this isn't a "**nav blocking itself**" problem.  this is a "**nav overrides anything in the DOM above the nav**" problem.

```
<header>
  <a href="#"><img src="social.png"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="myLogo.png"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="thingy.png"></a>
</header>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default center">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-top">
      ... all the rest of the bootstrap nav crap ...
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

so the link on the image is blocked.  the nav component magically reaches to the top of the page and even if i set the index on the `<a>` or the `<img>`, it still won't fire.

padding the body doesn't work, because nothing is hidden and i'm happy with the layout.  for those who are needing a visual, here you go:

[image: nav blocks header image links]

the bluish area is part of the `<nav>` (marked in green) which sits below the `<header>` in the DOM... which makes no sense to me.  and it doesn't matter where the images is positioned, or how large/small it is, the `<nav>` will still cover it.

how the heck do i fix this?  obviously i want to be able to click these links and go... but the `<nav>` blocks them completely.

Comment: What version of bootstrap is this?

Comment: bs3 or bs4.  seems to do the same on either.

Comment: Check and see what CDN you're linking to in the header. The version may have a significant impact on the solution as they changed many things from 3 to 4. I also suggest you post up any custom CSS you may have made for the navbar or any classes that are used in it.

Comment: i have no custom css other than colour settings.  that's what is so irritating.  :P  i will change my CDN and see if that helps.